# Javascript - Nested loops adding 1?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested

For the following code:

```js
for (var x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
  for (var y = 1; y < 5; y++) { x += y}
}
console.log(x)
```

Why is the output showing 12?

Isn't the loop being calculated like this:

1+1+2+3+4 = 11

I'm not clear on where the extra 1 is added. Can someone help advise?

Comment: Your inner loop does nothing. Was there supposed to be a body to it?

Comment: where is the addition in the code?

Comment: that should be 2 and not 12

Comment: Post your full code please.

Comment: I got `2` as expected.

Comment: ah sorry somehow the part with x+=y was not included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra one is from `x++` in the first loop. You loop runs for `x=1` and inner loop does `1+1+2+3+4` = `11` but then it will do `x++` of first loop and becomes `12`. Before checking the condition your `increment` operation will be done

```js
for (var x = 1; x < 2; x++) {
    for (var y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
    x = x+y;
    }
    console.log("x inside loop- "+x);
}
console.log(x)
```

Comment: Glad I helped :)